# odoo11 view filter, last updated datetime

Tags: python, xml, odoo-11

I'm working on a Recipe app in Odoo11.
In the app, I have a model with fields Recipe, Ingredients and create_date that are displayed on a `TreeView`.

I would like to filter the fields so that for all the same recipe (eg. Pancake) there will be unique ingredients filtered from the latest created date.

For example:
The `TreeView` I have now is:

```
Recipe          ingredient         create_date
pancake         flour              d/m/y-h:m:s
pancake         flour              d/m/y-h:m:s
pancake         egg                d/m/y-h:m:s
pancake         egg                d/m/y-h:m:s
pancake         egg                d/m/y-h:m:s
pancake         butter             d/m/y-h:m:s
```

There are multiple ingredient entries (flour,egg) to the recipe:
pancake

What I would like is to filter out repeated ingredients and view only the one with the latest `create_date` like this:

```
Recipe          ingredient         create_date
pancake         flour              d/m/y-h:m:s
pancake         egg                d/m/y-h:m:s
pancake         butter             d/m/y-h:m:s
```

Take note that I do not want the repeated ingredients to be deleted.
Is this possible? And if so, how?